# Wordpress Header Nav Positioned Over Fullscreen Background Image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, background

I am using the pro-theme "Frame" for Wordpress and have not been able to find support elsewhere for an issue (developer of theme won't support plugin compatibility issues--understandably). I am trying to re-position header/nav so that it does not overflow onto background images, rather, the background images are positioned below the header/nav wrapper/container. I've been trying to fix this issue for a few days now and cannot find a solution.

For example: below the link will show the BG image of a woman and I would like her head to not be cropped/covered. I also need whatever changes to be responsive and work with the additional features on the site (i.e. - homepage has a slideshow, etc.).

[LINK](http://vanessagonzalez.net/wp/bio/)

Thank you for any help--it is much appreciated!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The HTML of the page is a mess. I suggest to modify the background image of the woman itself (with whatever editor you want), just add a top margin to the image, let's say 80px white colour.

This is the easiest solution. If you provide me more details were this background is generated/paced I may be able to give you the CSS solution.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback. I've added additional pixels to the top of the image and it doesn't look great on mobile, but it's the easiest fix.